# Node: Move the current directory of the interactive shell

Tags: node.js, shell

I'm writing a little CLI tool for Node.js. There are some situations where I'd like to run modify the current directory of the shell that runs my program:

```
some/location$ myProg moveToSomewhere
some/other/location$
```

`child_process` can't help here, since its commands run in a different shell.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hm, this would be controlling the parent process (the shell in this case), which I don't think is possible, or at least not platform-independent. You could perhaps start a new shell there (keepinng `myProg` running...), but that's all I _personally_ can think of.